# Make laptop wake when I touch the screen

Tags: sleep, touch

I have a HP elitebook G4 laptop which has a touch display with ten touch input points and would like to know how to configure windows 10 to detect when the screen is touched and wake the device or when the display is off while the machine is still on, same behavior. I would like to use the touch device as a wake up trigger, how can I do this?

Comment: You're more likely to get useful help if you're more specific than "a laptop". See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/learn-about-hardware/wakeontouch for some devices.

Comment: Right away, editing the post

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the device could wake the system from sleep in touchscreen properties in `Device Manager > Mice and other pointing devices` or by running this command from shell `powercfg /DEVICEQUERY wake_programmable`

You're out of luck if the touchscreen does not have wake property.

Comment: i got this info when i ran your command, is the fourth device the touch  
`Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8265
Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM
HID-compliant mouse (001)
HID-compliant vendor-defined device (002)`